# How to test a webService call code using JUnit in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, functional-testing, android-testing

I want to write the functional test cases for my android application. I am not talking about sending the click buttons or UI related events, i am mentioning about the code coverage or e.g. i want to check if my parser is working fine or not, does my login call is successful or not ? In short, how to write functional test cases, any links or tutorials are much appreciated.
Also any suggestions for setting the test framework for my project. I am working on Android Studio.

Comment: Test your web service response using Junit now...http://findnerd.com/list/view/Testing-Web-Service-response-using-Junit-in-Android/3193/

Answer (score 1):

First, add JUnit to the project, by adding this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then, make sure you have a test directory that is located on the same level as your main directory, like this:

```
app
└─── src
     ├─── main
     │    ├─── java
     │    │    └─── com.example.app
     │    └───res
     └─── test
          └─── java
               └─── com.example.app
```

Then you can go ahead and create a test class, for example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class LogicTest {
    @Test
    public void addingNumbersShouldReturnSum() {
        Logic logic = new Logic();

        assertEquals("2 + 2 must be 4", 4, logic.add(2, 2));
    }
}
```

You can run those tests on your debug build by executing `gradlew testDebug`, or from Android Studio if you have version 1.1 or later.
Check out http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support for more information.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the reply. So it means, my each and every method should have to return something so that the same can be verified in test class , is it? Then what about the cases for e.g. a successful login call where we directly navigate user to home page instead of returning something. Same applicable for my parser classes, they just set the data to the model classes,and not return anything . How these cases can be taken care of?

Comment: In that case you don't need unit tests, but integration tests. If you want to do that, the easiest thing to do is to set up Espresso: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

Comment: Test your web service response using Junit now...http://findnerd.com/list/view/Testing-Web-Service-response-using-Junit-in-Android/3193/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Robolectric for that. Check out [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) on how to set up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Test your web service response using Junit now...http://findnerd.com/list/view/Testing-Web-Service-response-using-Junit-in-Android/3193/